# How to fix multiplayer stuttering?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

For some reason the other player's movement is 'stuttering'. I know this is a common problem people run into with Photon, so was wondering if anyone knows how I can resolve it?

Here's my player movement code:

```
public float SmoothingDelay = 5;

public void Start() 
{
    GetComponent<SmoothSyncMovement>().enabled = true; //This is the name of this script
}

public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
{
    if (stream.isWriting)
    {
        //We own this player: send the others our data
        stream.SendNext(rb2D.position);
        stream.SendNext(rb2D.rotation); 
    }
    else
    {
        //Network player, receive data
        correctPlayerPos = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();

    }
}

public void Update()
{
    if (!photonView.isMine)
    {
        Vector2 playerMovement = rb2D.position + velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        rb2D.MovePosition(playerMovement);          
    }

    if (photonView.isMine)
    {
        Vector2 playerMovement = rb2D.position + velocity * Time.deltaTime;      
        rb2D.MovePosition(playerMovement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same topic discussed on ExitGames forum: http://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/6821/other-players-have-flashing-stuterring-movement

Answer (score 1):

Make a smooth transition between players old possible and new position, dont set position. You can use lerp for this or any other method.

This video tutorial goes into all the details of photon networking including how to deal with stuttering and other issues you might run into. [Video Tutorial Play List](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIgwZK151-A&list=PLbghT7MmckI7BDIGqNl_TgizCpJiXy0n9)

[Exact Video That Addresses Stuttering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZ7TQjWhtEw&index=6&list=PLbghT7MmckI7BDIGqNl_TgizCpJiXy0n9)

It would look something like this:

```
currentPosition = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, realPosition,0.1f);
```

Where currentPosition is the position of the networked player before it moves on your client and realPosition is the new position received from the network where you want the player to be.

Comment: So I replace stream.SendNext(rb2D.position);  and Vector2 playerMovement = rb2D.position + velocity * Time.deltaTime;      
        rb2D.MovePosition(playerMovement);  with a lerp? Thanks

Comment: For all players that are not the main character when the new position of does players come in, instead of setting the position and rotation of does objects use a lerp to transition between the old state and the new state. Im not sure how you can do this based on your exact implementation. For instance the variable "correctPlayerPos"  is never being used in your example. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-deal-with-a-stutter-movement.145515/ check last post on page.